# Octave, barplot, linestyle none

Tags: bar-chart, octave, linestyle

The following code:

```
data = rand(4, 5);

figure
h4 = bar(data, "stacked", "linestyle", "none");
l4 = legend("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5");
legend(l4, "location", "northeastoutside");
```

produces a plot that has no lines around the rectangles, as can be seen in the following screenshot:
[image]

However, when saved, be it via the menu or programmatically, the borders appear:
[image]

This happens when saving as PNG, EPS or PDF. Am I missing some option to generate the boxes without the border?

Thanks in advance,

Rodrigo

Comment: Nope. The boxes are still surrounded by a black line.

Comment: No, sorry. The borders still appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear all; close all; clc;
data = rand(4, 5);
figure
h4 = bar(data, "stacked", "linestyle", "none");
l4 = legend("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5");
h=legend(l4, "location", "northeastoutside");
axis off;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add an explanation why this works.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that the results are the same---minus the axes. The boxes continue to appear with a border when saved as PDF.